# My welcome on_member_join code isn't working for some reason and i can't seem to get it right (3days of experience in coding)

Tags: discord.py

This is my Code for to make my bot say a message in the specific channel with the id in get_channel to post a messages using embeds.

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    if member.guild.name == 'Ruthyon°•○♧':
        embed=discord.Embed(title="Welcome to {member.guild.name}", url="https://discord.gg/ZzEzeEDD9K", description="", color=discord.Color.blue())
        embed.set_author(name=member.author.display_name, icon_url=member.author.avatar_url)
        embed.set_thumbnail(url="#enter your own url")
        embed.add_field(name="Intro", value="Thank you for joining us, we hope you'll enjoy your time here in our community!", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Get started.", value="Head over to #╽»♡┆rules get verified and checkout the custom roles channel.", inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="Joined", value=member.joined_at)
        embed.set_image(url="#enter your own url")
        embed.set_footer(text="Information requested by: {}".format(member.author.display_name))
        embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        await client.get_channel(869616505795514425).send(f"{member.mention}")
        await client.get_channel(869616505795514425).send(embed=embed)
```

The problem is this:

```
Ignoring exception in on_member_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 27, in on_member_join
    embed.set_author(name=member.author.display_name, icon_url=member.author.avatar_url)
AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'author'
```

Comment: Is that traceback complete? I don't see the actual error message or exception raised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are doing `member.author` where member represents `discord.Member` and it doesn't have any `author` attribute. You can just do `member.avatar_url` to get their avatar. Same goes for `member.display_name`.